# assertion for how to use $x$ in function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

in the function $f$($x-2\over2x$)=$2x+5$ why we dont use ($x-2\over2x$) directly as a $X$ ? because as a basic rule in functions we have $f(x)$=$2x+5$ so that why ($x-2\over2x$)cant take $x$ place?
I will show a example:

$f$($x-2\over2x$)=$2x+5$ find $f^{-1}$$(3)$=?

$2x+5$=$3$

$2x$=$-2$

$x$=$-1$ now we have first x here

($x-2\over2x$)=($-1-2\over -2$)=($3\over2$)

now we have $f$($3\over2$) why we did'nt use $3\over2$ or ($x-2\over2x$) as a $x$ in $2x+5$ and than put it =$3$

Answer (score 1):

Call $g(x)=\frac{x-2}{2x}$ and then the expression is $f\circ g(x)=2x+5$. To find $f^{-1}(3)$ use that $(f\circ g)^{-1}(y)=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: for more examples would you please tell me the name of this filed in function?

Answer (score 0):

### Corrected Question

The question was incorrect to begin with. It should ask:
$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$
$\def\less{\smallsetminus}$

> Given a function $f : \rr\less\{\frac12\} \to \rr$ such that $f(\frac{x-2}{2x}) = 2x+5$ for every $x \in \rr\less\{0\}$, find $f^{-1}(3)$.

### Correct Solution

The solution you gave is also logically incorrect.

Given $y \in \rr\less\{\frac12\}$ such that $f(y) = 3$:

Note that for any $x \in \rr\less\{0\}$ we have that $\frac{x-2}{2x} = y$ iff $x-2 = 2xy$ iff $x = \frac{2}{1-2y}$.

Let $a = \frac{2}{1-2y}$.

Then $\frac{a-2}{2a} = y$ and hence $3 = f(y) = f(\frac{a-2}{2a}) = 2a+5$.

Thus $a = -1$ and hence $y = \frac{(-1)-2}{2(-1)} = \frac32$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(3) = \frac32$.

### Comments

The question is **wrong** because it did not specify the domain. For example let $g : \rr \to \rr$ such that $g(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \in \rr \less \{\frac12\}$ and also $g(\frac12) = 3$. Then $g(\frac12) = g(\frac32) = 3$, and so $g$ has no inverse function.

One also **cannot** just say that a function is defined to have the implied domain, even if the domain is a subset of $\rr$. For example it is **meaningless** to 'define' a function $h$ such that "$h(x^2) = x$", because without specifying what $x$ must be, the only reasonable convention is to assume that it can be any real number, which gives $1 = h(1^2) = h((-1)^2) = -1$. Furthermore, you are **lucky** that the question has "$f(\frac{x-2}{2x})$", because it **so happens** that $\frac{x-2}{2x}$ is different for different nonzero $x$, otherwise the question would be meaningless.